# how to load text file into flash using AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

How to load text file into flash using AS3 . and the text file not on the root but on my server on the internet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are already a few posts about this.

Here are 2 examples: [Flash AS3 Read Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400433/flash-as3-read-text-file)
and [Working with txt file on as3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198428/working-with-txt-file-on-as3)

What part, specifically, are you stuck on?

**UPDATE:**

```
var url:String = "http://concept-vs.com/load/my_text_file.txt";
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(url));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
function onFileLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    var loader:URLLoader = e.target as URLLoader;
    var text:String = loader.data; // variable text now holds the text from the file
}
```

Comment: i want't know ... how i load file like this .... (http://concept-vs.com/load/my_text_file.txt)

Comment: Answer has been updated to show exactly how to load the URL you stated.